# MySQL, get information using 2 tables

Tags: mysql

There are two tables: wp_users and wp_usermeta.

the wp_users table is structured like this:

```
id | email
---------------
1  | b@foo.com
2  | k@bah.com
```

the wp_usermeta table is structured like this:

```
id | user_id | meta_key                | meta_value
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | firstname               | bob
2  | 1       | lastname                | smith
3  | 1       | app_prefferedcategories | {"blog_id":"5"},{"blog_id":"22"}
4  | 2       | firstname               | jan
5  | 2       | lastname                | jones
6  | 2       | app_prefferedcategories | {"blog_id":"1"},{"blog_id":"7"}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get all e-mail adresses from users that have a meta_value of {"blog_id":"5"} in meta_key app_prefferedcategories.
I know how to query one table at a time, but i am having dificulties to join them.
Can anyone shine a light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.email
FROM wp_users u
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta um ON u.id = um.user_id
WHERE um.meta_key = 'app_prefferedcategories' AND um.meta_value LIKE '%{"blog_id":"5"}%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.email
from wp_usermeta m
inner join wp_users u on u.id = m.user_id
where meta_key = 'app_prefferedcategories'
and find_in_set('{"blog_id":"5"}', meta_value) > 0
```